# Reading large csv files using pandas with specifying dtypes giving memory error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, kaggle

I am trying to read expedia data from Kaggle which contains a 4GB csv file I tried reading it using `pd.read_csv('filename')` and got memory error. Second approach I tried reading particular columns only using the code:

`pd.read_csv('train.csv', dtype={'date_time':np.str, user_location_country': np.int32, 'user_location_region':np.int32, 'user_location_city':np.int32, 'orig_destination_distance':np.float64, 'user_id':np.int32})`

this again gives me memory error but using another modification of the same method which is:

`train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', dtype={'user_id':np.int32,'is_booking':bool, 'srch_destination_id':np.int32, 'hotel_cluster':np.int32},                usecols=['date_time', 'user_id', 'srch_ci', 'srch_co', 'srch_destination_id', 'is_booking', 'hotel_cluster'])'`

reads the data in about 5 minutes.

My problem is I want to read more columns using any of the methods but both fails and gives `Memory error`. I am using 8GB RAM with 8GB swap space so reading only 7-8 columns out of 24 columns in the data will reduce the data size around 800MB so no issues on the hardware usage.
I also tried reading in chunks that I don't want to do based on the algorithms that I am going to read in the later part.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, reading a csv file requires more memory than its size on the disk (I do not know how much more though).

You can find an alternative way to process your file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I already tried that converting the data into chunks that is what I don't want.